# How can I ensure a blank line before every new prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, clink, cmder

I'm using the Cmder package for my Windows command line environment. Some commands don't create a blank line after they've completed, which can make it more difficult to see every command that's been run. Is there a way to customize the command prompt so that it prints a new line before displaying the path and prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic DOS prompt is `c:\Windows>` which is set by using the system variable PROMPT to "$P$G".  (With newer versions of Windows, it's not an environment variable but you can still use the `prompt` command to set it.)

Change the value for PROMPT to add **`$_`** where you see fit.  That will add a new linefeed to the prompt.  I added *`$s`* to get a space after the >.

```
C:\Users\me> prompt $P$_$G$s

C:\Users\me
> dir \

   Volume in drive C has no label.
   Volume Serial Number is 5CE6-9877

   Directory of C:\
   08/22/2013  08:22 AM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
   03/05/2014  10:25 AM    <DIR>          Program Files
   03/05/2014  10:26 AM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
   01/22/2014  05:14 PM    <DIR>          Users
   01/22/2014  06:15 PM    <DIR>          Windows
           0 File(s)              0 bytes
           5 Dir(s)  36,451,704,832 bytes free

C:\Users\me
>
```

BTW, the list of prompt options can be found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490977.aspx

Comment: That worked for me. In my Cmder implementation, I needed to modify the @prompt variable in `Cmdr\vendor\init.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$_` to your Prompt environment variable to add a new line before showing the wanted prompt.

So assuming your prompt is the standard `$p$g`to get prompt like `c:\directory>`, change it as such:

`set prompt=$_$p$g`

> $_       Carriage return and linefeed

Use [`Setx`](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) to set it permanently.

[More info on Prompt](http://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html)